# Symfony 3.4 - how are forms whose actions point to a different controller handled?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to process a form in a separate controller.  While the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/action_method.html) show how to change a form's action and method, they don't show how the controller selected in `$form->setAction()` is actually supposed to handle the form.  Is it present in `Request`?  Do we make another `Form` object so we can check `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()`?

It's a pretty glaring omission.

Comment: exactly the same way as usual https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

**Controller for displaying the form**

```
/**
 * @route("/form", name="form_route")
 */
public function formAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('task_route'))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**Controller to handle submission**

> Is it present in Request?

Yes, the form data is in the request.

> Do we make another Form object so we can check `$form->isSubmitted()` and `$form->isValid()`?

The form has to be recreated so that you can handle and validate the request.

```
/**
 * @route("/task", name="task_route")
 */
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('task', TextType::class)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $task = $form->getData();
        /* ... */
    }

    //render task to view submission
    return $this->render('task.html.twig', [
        'task' => $task,
    ]);
}
```

This does have some duplicate code even when using entities and [Symfony's Form Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html#creating-form-classes), which is why [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/forms.html#handling-form-submits) recommends using the same controller for processing forms.